# Axis2 and customizing an XML schema in a bottom-up approach

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, apache-axis

I am using axis2 to create a web service from a java class I created.  Everything works well, but I'd like to be able to customize the wsdl and I cannot figure out how to do it.  I tried using some JAXB annotations with my objects (using axis1) but it had no effect on the wsdl generation.

I'd like to be able to specify nillable=true for some elements and make others required.  I'd also like to be able to change element names and other things.  Shouldn't axis2 look at the JAXB2.0 annotations if there's no WSDL included in the META-INF folder?

I have been trying to google how to map out the schema in a bottom-up approach but I have not had luck.  The axis2 website only shows basic steps for creating a web service or a client, but nothing about customizing the schema.

Comment: I too would love an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse.org you find (Eclipse Helios) Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers which is useful to create a web service easily and you can look at the documentation once for use of it effectively.